# CSS box not working, keeps highlighting text

Tags: css, highlight, box

I'm just trying to put my text in a grey box at the top of the page. What ends up with is the text just looks like highlighted.

```css
box1 {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<box1><strong>Note:</strong> Some of these resources are free, and some aren’t. Those that are paid resources are affiliate products or services, meaning if you buy them, I get a commission at no extra cost to you.&nbsp;Please know that I have personal experience
  with all of the following resources, which is why I recommend them.</box1>
```

Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: There is no `box1` tag in HTML.

Comment: Please add the relevant code, markup, script, etc.. instead of linking to a side which may or may not exhibit the problem in the future. See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details. Ones your linked site changes this question is redundant and of no use to any future user with similar issues.

Comment: Use Div tag instead of <box1> tag

Comment: Tip: Follow a html course, e.g. https://www.codecademy.com/learn/web

Answer (score 3):

I inspected your code in web inspector. Simply change box1 to class and not tag. Then wrap the text in

```css
.box1 {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<p class="box1"><strong>Note:</strong> Some of these resources are free, and some aren’t. Those that are paid resources are affiliate products or services, meaning if you buy them, I get a commission at no extra cost to you.&nbsp;Please know that I have personal experience
  with all of the following resources, which is why I recommend them.</p>
```